# How do I start a stopped Minecraft Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

How do I reopen a Minecraft Server? I stopped the server by accident and don't know how to restart it.

I entered the `/stop` command. I am using a Macbook if that's relevant.

Comment: Uh, just start it again?

Comment: Uhm I Can't ;-;

Comment: How did you start it the first time then? Just repeat that.

Comment: Well I Opened The Server But Now I Cant ;-; And Then When I Go To minecraft and open the server it says host is down ;-;

Answer (score 3):

You need to do whatever it is you did that initially started the server.

You will not be able to load Minecraft to "start" said server because it isn't running.  If it is not your server, you need to contact the person that runs it to start it back up again.

If you are running the server on your own computer, then click on whatever shortcut or run whatever command that started the server.

If this is not your computer, either a friend's personal computer or an online hosting service, contact whoever is in charge to get it started again.

Comment: Well When I Open The Server And Go To Minecraft It Still Says The Server host is Down ;-;

Comment: That's because you still haven't done anything I said.  Do you know who is responsible for initially starting the server?  Did you contact that person?

Comment: I Am The Owner Of The Server And I Opened The "java 1.12.1 server" It was running perfectly but still when i open it it still says server host is down and im running minecraft with the minecraft server running... ;-;

Comment: You may own it, but it doesn't seem like you have any idea what you even did to start the server.  Did you type in your IP incorrectly?

Comment: Im Not Sure ;-; Because I Used The Normal Ip That It Put There, 25565 and   i also used my public ip and it still both said host is down... Ps: I Used the server properties to put my ip

Comment: Omg Im A Idiot Nelson,..... I Think I Put The Wrong Ip Adress In The Minecraft server and thats why it didnt work.... Thanks Nelson!